# How to Update Frequency of clicked button

Tags: c#

Hi I am writing some code for my homework and I am stuck. I created one general click event handler for digit Buttons:

```
private void btnN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e),
```

and now I need to make frequency Array which I need to update every time when one of the button is clicked. 
Here is freqArray:

```
private int[] freqArray = new int[10];
```

How can I do that if there is let say nine buttons?
Thank you

lastNum is number of buttons.

```
private void btnN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                for (int i = 0; i < lastNum; i++)
                {
                    freqArray[i]++;
                    lstFrequencies.Items[i] = i + "\t\t" + freqArray[i];

                }
        }
```

Comment: You want us to write your homework for you?  Doesnt that defeat the point of homework?  I think you'd get a better response if you posted the code you've tried and the error's you've received.

Comment: Hm... Of course I dont want you to write my homework that is why i didnt post the whole thing just one small part that I am stuck on! The problem is that I really cant figure this out cose I just started with c#

Comment: I can appreciate that, however, the question as its phrased is very non specific.  It reads like "gimme da codez for nine buttons".  My initial suggestion still stands.  Better to post what you've done, discuss where it's broken and then we'll find the fix in no time.

Comment: Here is a hint: You will want to identify the right button to count the right number up, right? Look at the sender parameter and also at `casting` objects!

Comment: Here is another hint: Quite often you will find that the result of your thinking will in fact be better than stuff you pull from the web   ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gosh, this is getting out of hand.. but since the original idea of giving hints and helping you along the way has hit the wall - I'll discuss the problem and will leave the decision to you..

The core problem is to identify within the common click event just which of the many buttons has been clicked. The key to this is usually in the event's parameters; in this case the `sender` is the button that got clicked.

We will look at **three** different ways to identify the sender:

- By comparing it to the `Control`
- By looking at its `Name`
- By using an index stored in its `Tag`

So the simplest and most direct approach would be something like this:

```
if (sender == button1) freqArray[0]++; 
else if (sender == button2) freqArray[1]++; 
..
```

Note that while the designer names the controls you add with a count from 1 the programmers count from 0! (As do many data structures in C# including your array of counts!)

There are other approaches and since we are doing a little lesson here we go:

Sender is of the most basic type `object`; you can cast an object to its actual Type like this:

```
Button b = (Button) sender;
```

And now you can access all the button's properties, including the Name. So you could write the above code like this:

```
if (b.Name == "button1") freqArray[0]++; 
else if (b.Name == "button2") freqArray[1]++; 
..
```

This has un-coupled the actual button control from the identification and replaced it by a string.

And there is a general purpose property called `Tag`, which incidentally is also of class object; you can store *anything* in it. This makes it sometimes quite valuable and often one creates a special structure or even class just to store many things in a Tag..

So if you have created the Buttons to have their Tag contain an index you could use that:

```
freqArray[ (int) ( (Button) sender).Tag)   ]++;
```

Note the double casts and all those parenthesis! It looks complicated and it is. It is just one line instead of the long vector of if clauses we saw before. But it only works if you have set the Tags before, maybe in the load event:

```
button1.Tag = 0;
button2.Tag = 1;
button3.Tag = 2;
...
```

So you have to invest first and can harvest later..

A lot to digest here.. Your pick!

Comment: @Zile: Have you completed your task?

Comment: Thank you so much for this tutorial TaW I did it this way: for(int j = 0; j < number; j++)
            {
                btnNums[j] = new Button();
                btnNums[j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
                btnNums[j].Name = "btn" + j;
                btnNums[j].Tag = j; // I put the tag here while creating buttons
                btnNums[j].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 23);
                btnNums[j].Text = j.ToString();
                btnNums[j].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                btnNums[j].Click += new System.EventHandler(btnN_Click);

Comment: And then update frequency here   private void btnN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            freqArray[(int)((Button)sender).Tag]++;
            lstFrequencies.Items[(int)(((Button)sender).Tag)] = ((Button)sender).Text + "\t\t" + freqArray[(int)((Button)sender).Tag];
        }

Answer (score 1):

One thing you must understand is you shouldn't ask for approach to a problem. However since your question requires it.

First you should add Tags to the buttons to differentiate them:

```
button1.Tag = "1";
button2.Tag = "2";
.
.
.
```

Then in your event handler cast the sender object to your control type:

```
Button a = (button)sender;
```

Then check the tag of the button a to add frequencies:

```
   freqArray[Convert.ToString(a.Tag)-48] = freqArray[Convert.ToString(a.Tag)-48] + 1;
```

Comment: Mostly I'm opposed to answering this question, but I do like the comment about not asking for an approach to a problem.

Comment: @paqogomez I oppose these answering too (give a man a fish, he eats for a day; teach a man to fish, he eats for a lifetime).